# Pandas not returning values in same row on conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I create a simple dataframe and I add on some columns

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'price': [6, 5.5, 5, 4.8],
    'amount': [10, 12, 8, 6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['total'] = df.price * df.amount
df['running_total'] = df.total.cumsum().round(2)
```

my dataframe now looks like this:

```
   amount  price  total  running_total
0      10    6.0   60.0           60.0
1      12    5.5   66.0          126.0
2       8    5.0   40.0          166.0
3       6    4.8   28.8          194.8
```

I want the row from the dataframe with running total just under 160:

```
row_under_160 = df[df['running_total'] < 160].max()
```

This row (series) looks like this:

```
amount            12.0
price              6.0
total             66.0
running_total    126.0
dtype: float64
```

All the values look good EXCEPT PRICE.  For some reason it's returning the top price (6.0) when it should return 5.5 which is the corresponding value.

Am I missing something/doing this entirely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It working very nice, but `max` value is count from filtered `DataFrame`:

```
row_under_160 = df[df['running_total'] < 160]
print (row_under_160)
   amount  price  total  running_total
0      10    6.0   60.0           60.0
1      12    5.5   66.0          126.0
```

Get max values of each column:

```
print (row_under_160.max())
amount            12.0
price              6.0
total             66.0
running_total    126.0
dtype: float64
```

But it seems need index of filtered DataFrame where `running_total` is `max` by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and select by `loc`:

```
print (row_under_160['running_total'].idxmax())
1

print (row_under_160.loc[row_under_160['running_total'].idxmax()])
amount            12.0
price              5.5
total             66.0
running_total    126.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

If need one row `DataFrame` add `[]`:

```
print (row_under_160.loc[[row_under_160['running_total'].idxmax()]])
   amount  price  total  running_total
1      12    5.5   66.0          126.0
```

Or compare by `max` value:

```
print (row_under_160[row_under_160['running_total'] == row_under_160['running_total'].max()])
   amount  price  total  running_total
1      12    5.5   66.0          126.0
```

Comment: This not only answered the question, but provided some great clarification for using methods on dataframes (I thought incorrectly that max was returning a row, but it was returning max values in all columns for the resulting dataframe).  Thank you very much!!!